# bcbankApp.accsummary module AccountSummaryController should have a getAccountSummary function FAILED in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

I am working on Banking app using Angularjs on hackerrank  where I am stuck at point.I am trying to call my function from Account summary controller but It is saying that No such function exist in my controller

Here is my code

**AccountSummarycontroller.js**

```
 // Create the controller AccountSummaryController with getAccountSummary function that access accountSummaryService which is already defined in account-summary.service.js. Use $state for Transition from one page to another.


(function() {
    'use strict';
   var appContr = angular.module('abcbankApp.accountSummary', ['abcbankApp.accountSummaryService']);
    appContr.controller('AccountSummaryController', function(AccountSummaryService) {
    var ActSumCtrl = this;
   // this.AccountSummaryService.getAccountSummary();
    ActSumCtrl.accountList = [];
    ActSumCtrl.accountList = AccountSummaryService.getAccountSummary();
    });

})();
```

**AccountSumaaryService.js**

```
// Create the service AccountSummaryService with getAccountSummary function which should return the account details from data/account-summary.json using $http.get.

(function() {
    'use strict';

     var appServc = angular.module('abcbankApp.accountSummaryService', []);
appServc.factory('AccountSummaryService', ['$http',
  function($http) {
    return {
      getAccountSummary: function() {
          var data;
          $http.get('./data/account-summary.json')
         .then(function(response) {
           data = response.data;
        });
        return data;
      }
    };
  }]);

})();
```

But I am getting error something like below

**abcbankApp.accsummary module AccountSummaryController should have a getAccountSummary function FAILED.Expected false to be true.**

**Testfile.js**

```
  describe('AccountSummaryController', function() {

            it('Controller definition', function() {
                expect(AccountSummaryController).toBeDefined();
            });



            it('should have a getAccountSummary function', function() {
                expect(angular.isFunction(AccountSummaryController.getAccountSummary)).toBe(true);
            });

        });
    });

})();
```

Any Help will be Appreciated.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well to answer your question lets begin with your test case as it is showing that **AccountSummaryController.getAccountSummary** should be defined

So you should call your function with your controller name and function name

Here is modified code

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
   var appContr = angular.module('abcbankApp.accountSummary', ['abcbankApp.accountSummaryService']);
    appContr.controller('AccountSummaryController', function(AccountSummaryService) {
    var ActSumCtrl = this;
   // this.AccountSummaryService.getAccountSummary();


    ActSumCtrl.accountList = [];
     ActSumCtrl.getAccountSummary=function()
    {
       //move your logic here
    }
    ActSumCtrl.accountList = AccountSummaryService.getAccountSummary();
    });

})();
```

Let me know in comment weather it worked or not